# Erlang/Yaws: Cannot start web server within application using .conf file

Tags: erlang, yaws

I'm kind of at a loss. YAWS works fine starting as a service during boot in LXQt 19.04. But I intended on using a rate limiter; setting it in `arg_rewrite_mod`. Having one VM run YAWS and another my application, setting code paths appropriately, I believe would yield subpar performance because the rate limiting calls would use OS-based IPC and not Erlang IPC. Hence there should be OS IPC overhead and not EVM overhead, correct?

I basically just wanted everything under one hood to eliminate that. This is one thing were there are probably a few ways to approach the problem (i.e. split up my project and duplicate pieces where needed) but I like the "simplicity" of everything in one place.

I'm getting an error, `{badmatch, {error, enoent}}`, in the shell after:

```
code:add_patha("/usr/lib/yaws/ebin").
application:start(yaws).
```

It is occurring on line 548 in `yaws_server:setup_dirs/1` ([Github](https://github.com/klacke/yaws/blob/master/src/yaws_server.erl))

```erlang
setup_dirs(GC) ->
    Dir = yaws:id_dir(GC#gconf.id),
    Ctl = yaws:ctl_file(GC#gconf.id),
    ok = filelib:ensure_dir(Ctl),
    case file:list_dir(Dir) of
        {ok, LL} ->
            lists:foreach(
              fun(F) ->
                      file:delete(filename:join([Dir, F]))
              end, LL -- ["CTL"]); %%%  <---- LINE 548
        {error, RSN} ->
            error_logger:format("Failed to list ~p probably "
                                "due to permission errs: ~p",
                                [Dir, RSN]),
            erlang:error(RSN)
    end.
```

I made a UNIX group `appname` consisting of myself and the user `yaws`. I've gone around to various directories I found with `sudo find / -group yaws -type d` and set group permissions to the same as owner as well as reassigning the group from `yaws` to `appname`.... I believe since I did not set the `id` it is `"default"`. My logs (`/var/log/yaws/report.log`) I was hoping would indicate the problem. They are empty.

I'm essentially using the default `/etc/yaws/yaws.conf` file. The server section has been removed and placed in `/etc/yaws/conf.avail/` with a symlink in `/etc/yaws/conf.d/`.

**UPDATE:** The crash report ----

```erlang
2020-03-27T08:30:04.131073-05:00 notice: Yaws: Using config file /etc/yaws/yaws.conf

2020-03-27T08:30:04.136142-05:00 error: use_old_ssl in yaws.conf is no longer supported - ignoring

2020-03-27T08:30:04.137441-05:00 notice: Yaws: Using global subconfig file /etc/yaws/conf.d/localhost.conf

2020-03-27T08:30:04.140979-05:00 error:
    crasher:
        initial call: yaws_server:init/1,
        pid: <0.114.0>,
        registered_name: [],
        error: {{badmatch,{error,enoent}},
            [{yaws_server,setup_dirs,1,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,548}]},
            {yaws_server,init2,5,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,224}]},
            {gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},
            {gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},
            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]},
        ancestors: [yaws_sup,<0.108.0>],
        message_queue_len: 0,
        messages: [],
        links: [<0.109.0>,#Port<0.6>],
        dictionary: [{gc,{gconf,"/usr/lib/yaws",false,612,"/var/log/yaws",
                ["/usr/local/lib/yaws-appmods/ebin","/usr/lib/yaws/examples/ebin"],
                [],[],30000,nolimit,400,1000000,8000,nolimit,[],10240,[],0,30,
                ["/usr/local/lib/yaws-appmods/include","/usr/lib/yaws/examples/include"],
                "/usr/bin/php-cgi","Yaws 2.0.6","default",false,[],8,undefined,
                [inet],yaws_session_server,undefined,120000,3600000,disable}},
        {start_time,{{2020,3,27},{8,30,4}}}],
        trap_exit: true,
        status: running,
        heap_size: 1598,
        stack_size: 27,
        reductions: 32410;
    neighbours:

2020-03-27T08:30:04.141195-05:00 error:
    supervisor: {local,yaws_sup},
    errorContext: start_error,
    reason: {{badmatch,{error,enoent}},
        [{yaws_server,setup_dirs,1,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,548}]},
        {yaws_server,init2,5,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,224}]},
        {gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},    
        {gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},
        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]},
    offender: [{pid,undefined},
        {id,yaws_server},
        {mfargs,
            {yaws_server,start_link,
                [{env,false,false,false,false,false,false,"default",latin1}]}},
        {restart_type,permanent},
        {shutdown,120000},
        {child_type,worker}]

2020-03-27T08:30:04.145621-05:00 error: 
    crasher:
        initial call: application_master:init/4,
        pid: <0.107.0>,
        registered_name: [],
        exit: {{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,yaws_server,{{badmatch,{error,enoent}},
            [{yaws_server,setup_dirs,1,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,548}]},
            {yaws_server,init2,5,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,224}]},
            {gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},
            {gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},
            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}}},
        {yaws_app,start,[normal,[]]}},
            [{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,138}]},
            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]},
        ancestors: [<0.106.0>],
        message_queue_len: 1,
        messages: [{'EXIT',<0.108.0>,normal}],
        links: [<0.106.0>,<0.43.0>],
        dictionary: [],
        trap_exit: true,
        status: running,
        heap_size: 987,
        stack_size: 27,
        reductions: 225;
    neighbours:

2020-03-27T08:30:04.147171-05:00 notice:
    application: yaws,
    exited: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,yaws_server,{{badmatch,{error,enoent}},
        [{yaws_server,setup_dirs,1,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,548}]},
        {yaws_server,init2,5,[{file,"yaws_server.erl"},{line,224}]},
        {gen_server,init_it,2,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,374}]},
        {gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,342}]},
        {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},
        {line,249}]}]}}},{yaws_app,start,[normal,[]]}},
    type: temporary
```

**SOLUTION:**
From the help from the answer below and from having explored the various YAWS paths using `find` above I found the "default" home directory for me was `/var/cache/yaws/'. The following series of commands in the shell worked for me:

```erlang
os:putenv("YAWSHOME","/var/cache/yaws/").
code:add_patha("/usr/lib/yaws/ebin").
application:start(yaws).
```

Comment: Can you show more details from your crash reports?

Comment: Be happy to... let me familiarize myself with the logger. Will update when I do.

Comment: Great, thanks for the added crash report info. Another question: what version of Yaws are you running?

Comment: I'm running 2.0.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code line 548 shown in your question can't return `{error, enoent}`, but line 548 of `yaws_server.erl` for version 2.0.6 is

```
ok = filelib:ensure_dir(Ctl),
```

and this is what's returning the error tuple, which fails to match the expected atom `ok` and causes the failure.

The function [`filelib:ensure_dir/1`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/filelib.html#ensure_dir-1) verifies that the parent directories of its argument exist, attempting to create them if they don't. Solving this problem therefore requires determining the `Ctl` argument pathname in the code shown above.

Since your server id is "default", `Ctl` in this case is defined as the path

```
<HOME>/.yaws/yaws/default/CTL
```

where `<HOME>` comes either from the setting for the `YAWSHOME` environment variable if it exists, otherwise from the setting for the `HOME` environment variable. Make sure one of these environment variables is set to a suitable path and that the `.yaws/yaws/default` subdirectory under it, if already present, has the appropriate permissions for your `yaws` user id and `appname` group id.

Comment: Thank you. I did keep tinkering trying to start an embedded session. I purposefully left out `ensure_dir/1` and saw a directory tree in a sequence of errors similar to what I saw under `/var/cache/yaws`. So I suspected this but would have ever found the environmental variable. I also didn't realize I had to relog to have group changes take effect.